# iOS 10 Notification Content Extension: using NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, notifications, ios10

I'm trying to create a new Notification Content Extension in iOS 10 for local notifications where the notification view controller responsible for the content extension downloads an image from the network and renders it in a UIImageView. I have the Notification Content Extension target set up with an appropriate Info.plist and the content extension works beautifully for simple things like rendering a label with some content, for example the sample code that comes in the template:

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    self.label.text = notification.request.content.body
}
```

However, when I try to introduce NSURLSession (or URLSession in Swift 3) into the mix, the notification content totally fails to load - not even the label gets set anymore:

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {

    self.label.text = notification.request.content.body
    let session = URLSession.shared()
    let url = URL(string: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World")!

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: url) { (fileURL, response, error) in
        if let path = fileURL?.path {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:path)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Is the usage of NSURLSession in the notification content extension not allowed? Is my extension possibly being killed before the download completes? If so, how could I ensure that it's not killed so I can download and render the image?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, changing transport app security doesn't do anything, no relevant logs either, and I've seen no documentation talking about it so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point when `func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification)` is called in the Content extension, any modifications to the content such as downloading images should have already occurred.

It seems that you use a Notification **Service** Extension to do the downloading of any additional content. The Notification **Content** extension is only responsible for providing a custom user interface if you need one.

In your Service extension you download the image using the url in the notification payload, and set it as an attachment on the `UNNotification` object. If you don't need any custom UI, the system will automatically display visual media attachments like a video or an image. If that suits your needs, you don't actually need a Notification Content Extension at all.

Pusher provide a great tutorial on setting up a Notification Service Extension for handling media attachments in push notifications on iOS 10 [right here](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-send-ios-10-notifications-using-the-push-notifications-api/).

Comment: this isn't the correct answer lol. it's ending bc the networking task is async.

Comment: @Gukki5 don't create a semaphore and block in a content extension. A service extension is where you want to fetch and apply content for notifications.

Comment: oh i didn't know about the content extension, but ya I've been using the semaphore with a service extension

Comment: this does not seem to be true (at least on iOS 11), since I am able to use URLSession and download images in notification content extension

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to download images in a `Notification Content Extension`. However, your code contains two problems:

1. The URL is not valid.
2. The `fileURL` returned by the `downloadTask` methode is deleted as soon as the function runs out of scope, which is already the case when you try to access the `fileURL`from another thread. Instead it's better to catch the `fileURL` content in a data variable and use that to produce an image in the main thread

Slightly corrected code:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://betamagic.nl/images/coredatalab_hero_01.jpg") else {
    return
}

let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (fileURL, response, error) in
    if let fileURL = fileURL,
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
     }
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable app transport security in Info.plist for you extension.
Tip: move file from tmp folder to cache for save